# Python UnicodeDecodeError with 'gbk' while using third party libraries

Tags: python, encoding

I'm trying the examples in "PyDeepGP" provided by SheffieldML (https://github.com/SheffieldML/PyDeepGP). In the example code, a third-party library `pods` is used to provide some open datasets.

Once running the example code, I immediately encountered the error message:
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 37571: illegal multibyte sequence".
It turns out that the error occurs when the `pods` trying to open a file called 'data_resources.json' and do `file.read()` on it.

I manually `f = open("...\data_resources.json", encoding="utf8")` and then `f.read()`, everything will be fine. So it's obvious my python choose the 'gbk' to decode an 'utf8' file with unknown reason.

However, it is infeasible for me to add `encoding="utf8"` to every piece of code in a third-party library. I want to force my python opening file automatically with utf-8.

I checked the `sys.getdefaultencoding()` and it is 'utf8' as usual.
I have tried to set my vscode with `files.autoGuessEncoding` turning on and then off.
And I even tried the solution provided by http://www.programmersought.com/article/4189689383/, adding

```py
import _locale
_locale._getdefaultlocale = (lambda *args: ['zh_CN', 'utf8'])
```

to the codes. It will work only when I manually write `open(file) as f` and then `f.read()`. However it fails when I run the whole example code, where the file is open by the third-party library.

I am currently using python 3.6.7 on Windows 10 with Anaconda.

Here's the complete error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..../SheffieldML-PyDeepGP/examples/example_supervised_learning.py", line 35, in <module>
    import pods
  File "....\lib\site-packages\pods\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import datasets
  File "....\lib\site-packages\pods\datasets.py", line 53, in <module>
    json_data=open(path).read()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 37571: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Comment: Try setting the [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable to UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same error. I got some clue from
https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/issues/37
and change the `datasets.py` **line 53** as

```
json_data=open(path,'rb').read()
```

By using the binary mode, it will probably ignore the codec things.